# Max of two Date columns in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two date columns one is createDate and other is modifiedDate.
Now I want to get max if these two date columns.

```
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add( Projections.max("createdDate"));
```

How to add another date in Projection. and find max date of both.
Not able to find any specific way to do this.

Entity is :-

```
package com.xyz.DemoEntity;


import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Formula;


@Entity
public class DemoEntity {

    private Integer id;
    private Date createdOn;
    private Date modifiedOn;

    @Formula("CASE WHEN createdOn > modifiedOn THEN createdOn ELSE modifiedOn  END")
    private Date maxDate;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(updatable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }
    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getModifiedOn() {
        return modifiedOn;
    }

    public void setModifiedOn(Date modifiedOn) {
        this.modifiedOn = modifiedOn;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you give an sql query of what you are trying to do ?

Comment: I am using hibernate 4 and ms sql server.

Comment: have you tried to add another projection in projectionList like `projectionList.add( Projections.max("modifiedDate"));` ?

Comment: But I think it will give two different result. One is max of createdDate and second is max of modifiedDate.
But I need combined result of both.

Comment: Ehm. Is it really possible, that `createDate` > `modifiedDate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should introduce an artificial column annotated with @Formula

Like this

```
@Formula("CASE WHEN createDate > modifiedDate THEN createDate ELSE modifiedDate  END")
private Date maxDate;
```

And then use `projectionList.add( Projections.max("maxDate"));` to get max.

Comment: Is this field will persisted in the database ?

Comment: No. It's just kind of calculated field in SELECT block

Comment: getting this exception : org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: maxDate of: com.xyz.DemoEntity

Comment: Edit the question to include the com.xyz.DemoEntity

Comment: You don't have getter/setter for the maxDate